# How to I change the xslt applied to XML document in VS 2008 IDE?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, text, xslt-tools

I have an XML document and made an XSLT to output is as HTML and viewed the output in the IDE.  Now I want to create an XSLT to output as text file, but the 'Show XSLT Output' only shows me the HTML.  How do I switch it to the text output XSLT?

I even put in the line:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="NotaryExport.xslt" ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the XML document open, look in the Property Grid (F4). You'll see that  you have the Stylesheet property set to the original (HTML) stylesheet. Switch it to use the text stylesheet.

Comment: Jeez, wasn't looking there.  Looked everywhere in the menu though.